# Flutter/DART: Changing renderObject: RenderView size and display scaling issue

Tags: ios, flutter, render, display, scaling

I have downloaded a demo app, which scales fine on my iPhone 12 pro max and fits the whole display. However, on the app I am developing, I cannot for the life of me get my app to scale the whole display.

Here is the a photo of my app which does not take up the full screen.
[image]

Here is the devtools window size:
[image]

And here is the devtools window size for the demo app, which scales perfectly and fills the whole display:
[image]

Notice that the window size is much larger on the demo app. How do I go about changing the size in my app? I tried fitting a constrainedBox, sizeBox, customScrollView but nothing works since it seems to be constrained by the renderObject.

I am new to Flutter, any help is much appreciated.